# Angular cli default generation path

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to rename angular 2 directory structure. I want to name "src" folder to "SourceCode" and "app" folder inside "src" to "Application". I renamed the folders  as well as changed the angular-cli.json--->root to "SourceCode". Application works but when I am using angular-cli to generate component or anything. It automatically adds the "app" folder and then creates the files or folders inside. Angular cli generates path like this "SourceCode/app/...". I don't want angular cli to create "app" folder instead I want to use "Application" folder already created.

Any suggestion how to configure angular cli. ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you figure out a way for this.